# add elements to vector in a loop

Tags: c++, vector

the code I have problem is:

```
  vector<int> steps_list;
  steps_list.reserve(runs);

for (int i=0;i<runs;i++){
    int steps=0;
    bool in_con=false;
    srand(time(0));
    int init_pos=rand()%mylat;


    while (in_con==false) {

        srand(time(0));
        int step=2*(rand()%2)-1;

        init_pos+=step;

        init_pos=init_pos%grid.size();

        if (grid[init_pos]==0){

            in_con=true;
        }
        steps+=1;

    }

    steps_list.push_back(steps);

}



 for (int i=0;i<mylat;i++){
     cout<<steps_list[i]<<" ";
   }
```

I want to store in steps_list vector all the different steps ,but instead of that it stores only one step and it fills the vector with that.

I can't figure where is my problem.I am not familiar with vectors.

Comment: How is `in_con` defined?

Comment: @jens:As  bool in_con=false; above while and below for loop.

Comment: Under which conditions is `in_con` set to true? Can you maybe show more code.

Comment: @George if value of `in_con` is false, and the value will change in the `while` loop, then each iteration in the first `for` loop will have same result because value of `steps` will change in the same condition.

Comment: @mitchelllc:I updated.I must mention that the code runs fine in python with the same approach.

Comment: What is `mylat` and `grid`?

Comment: @Tomek:grid is a vector and mylat an int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move this line

```
    srand(time(0));
```

outside the loop, and preferably do this once at the beginning of your program.

You are seeding the random number generator, and my guess is the time you obtain has *second* resolution.  The loop iterations take less than a second, so you are always seeding with the same value and obtaining the same random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing but the error might be that you call `srand(time(0))` before each call of `rand()`. That's a very good way to make your random numbers completely **unrandom**.

Could that be an explanation for what you see?

In any case call `srand(time(0))` once at the beginning of the program and nowhere else.

Comment: :Ok,thanks.That was the error.Your answer was second though. :)

Comment: @George Yes by about 30 seconds I think